# Can you please help explain this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have this function that I'm trying to convert but I just cant understand what is happening in some parts of the code. Could anyone please help me out and explain the code. I just want to know what they do with the pointers. There are some blank comments in the code where they do hell with the pointers, i just dont get it.

Any help appreciated.

```
WORD** m_Pixels;

int pixel(int x, int y)
{

    if (x<0 || y<0 || x>=m_Width || y>=m_Height)
        return -1;

    WORD    *pPixels = m_Pixels[y];

    //
    int count = *pPixels++;

    int index = 0;

    register int i;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        i = count;
        do {
            // 
            index += *pPixels++;

            if (x < index)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            //      
            index += *pPixels;

            // 
            pPixels += *pPixels;

            pPixels++;


            // 
            index += *pPixels;

            // 
            pPixels += *pPixels;

            pPixels++;

            if (x < index)
            {
                return pPixels[x-index];
            }
        } while (--i);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code and what are the portions that you don't understand.

Comment: I just dont understand what they do, pPixels++;, what are they increasing?

Comment: Wow, that is some pretty ugly looking code

Comment: @Michael `I just dont understand what they do`. They just **play** with pointers. :)

Comment: It looks like your m_Pixels is a list of (header, data) sections for each y and it's walking through the structures until it's found the section with the xth pixel in it. pPixels++ is probably skipping over a value in the data header to the count they want. Someone could sit down and convert this code for you, yes, but it would make more sense for you to understand and convert the data structure it's reading from (assuming you write it yourself too - or is it a file you're reading in?)

Comment: I never wanted anyone to convert the code for me, just to explain the parts where I put blank comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int count = *pPixels++;
```

Dereferences the `pPixels` pointer to get the value and assigns it to `count` and increment the pointer - this will make the pointer to point to the next element in the array (`m_Pixels`)

---

```
index += *pPixels++;
```

Increment `index` with the value, pointed by `pPixels` and increment the pointer - this will make the pointer to point to the next element in the array

---

```
pPixels += *pPixels;
pPixels += *pPixels;
```

Move the pointer X positions ahead, where X is the value, pointed by `pPixels`

Comment: awesome mate =) I just wanted to verify, and everything seems right. Thanks!